# How can I create a DateInteveral to represent 1 day 2 hr 10 min 5 sec

Tags: swift

From DateInteveral init(), I need to specify 2 dates and it will calculate the time difference between the 2 days. https://cocoacasts.com/working-with-nsdateinterval-in-swift

My question is how can I create DateInteveral for a specify Inteveral say  1 day 2 hr 10 min 5 sec?  I see there is another class TimeInterval, but the unit is in seconds. Is convert back an d forth my interval into (1 day 2 hr 10 min 5 sec) to sec and save it in TimeInterval my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calendar method `date(byAdding:to:wrappingComponents:)` to add the desired DateComponents that represents that time interval to your `DateInterval` start date:

---

```
let start = Date()
let dateComponents = DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 2, minute: 10, second: 5)
let end = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: start)!
let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: start, end: end)
```

---

```
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day]
dcf.maximumUnitCount = 4
dcf.unitsStyle = .full
dcf.string(from: dateInterval.duration)  // "1 day, 2 hours, 10 minutes, 5 seconds"
```